# Why did my flight descend for landing then suddenly climb steeply and turn sharply?

Tags: airliner, landing, flight-planning

I was flying on a Vueling flight (VLG6251) from Rome, Italy to Orly, France on the 31st of December 2017. During landing, my plane went to a really low altitude as if it was about to land but there was no airport! I mean it was really low, and all of the sudden the plane sped up as if was taking off and it went to really high altitude really fast, while sharply turning to the left! Then I saw the airport. I checked the flight history of that flight and there was no history of it doing that.

Any suggestions on what was happening?

Comment: Just sounds like a go-around. When you say you checked the flight history where did you look? A radar track would pretty much tell if that's the case, but flights that far back are paywalled

Comment: Also bear in mind that the back of a plane is the worst possible place to see an airport. If it was an approach where the plane flew towards the runway from miles out then you would never see it

Answer (score 6):

According to data recorded on [Flightradar24](http://flightradar24.com) and the Planefinder App, that particular flight did not go around; however the turn to final approach was flown at lower altitude than some other flights that day (this seems different but not necessarily uncommon or abnormal, and happened for unknown reasons that cannot be inferred from the data).

Screenshot from the app:

[image: Screenshot]